# The connection to 'autodiscover.domain.com' fails using EWS

Tags: exchangewebservices, office365

I'm trying to start work with EWS using EWS-Api-2.1 nuget package. Below is simple code I'm using:

```
        ExchangeService _service = new ExchangeService();
        _service.Credentials = new WebCredentials("mail", "password");
        _service.AutodiscoverUrl("mail", url => false);//_service.AutodiscoverUrl("mail") Both variants fails

        var appointment = new Appointment(_service);
        appointment.Subject = "Status Meeting";
        appointment.Body = "The purpose of this meeting is to discuss status.";
        appointment.Start = DateTime.Now.AddHours(1);
        appointment.End = appointment.Start.AddHours(2);
        appointment.Location = "Conf Room";
        appointment.RequiredAttendees.Add("mail1");
        appointment.Save(SendInvitationsMode.SendToNone);
```

As result I have:

```
    HTTP/1.1 502 Fiddler - Connection Failed
    [Fiddler] The connection to 'autodiscover.domain.com' failed. 
    Error: ConnectionRefused (0x274d). System.Net.Sockets.SocketException
    No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it 157.56.248.169:443
```

In DNS management I have the following:

```
Initial domain: This domain is included with your account. It’s set up automatically for you, and you can’t delete it.
```

Comment: Do you know the exchange server's IP or its DNS name? Then you could try to setup the connection without autodiscover. This may give you a possibility to narrow down the cause.

Comment: Thanks for idea, it helped me to resolve issue. I've added next one code: _service.Url = new Uri("https://outlook.office365.com/EWS/Exchange.asmx");

Comment: Are you now able to use AutoDiscover?

Comment: I don't need to use AutoDiscover after adding this url.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to find out why Autodiscover is failing, I would recommend [enabling tracing](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dn495632(v=exchg.150).aspx) with all of the Autodiscover-related trace tags. Of course I'm assuming that the value "mail" that you're passing there is actually the user's email address.